# SSL implementation in VC++ MFC application with QuickFIX

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, openssl, mfc, quickfix

I am using quickfix lib with VC++ MFC 64-bit application, It is working fine. Now I want to use ThreadedSSLSocketAcceptor
I have done with the following:,

1. downloaded precompiled openssl-1.0.2l-vs2015.7z [md5] [from here][1](https://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-openssl/#_comments)
2. Added all the required openssl 64-bit header files.
3. define HAVE_SSL 1
4. link openssl 64-bit libs to application [ssleay32MDd.lib, libeay32MDd].

Still I am getting the following linking error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2028 unresolved token (0A0026BF) "public: __cdecl FIX::SSLSocketAcceptor::SSLSocketAcceptor(class FIX::Application &,class FIX::MessageStoreFactory &,class FIX::SessionSettings const &,class FIX::LogFactory &)" (??0SSLSocketAcceptor@FIX@@$$FQEAA@AEAVApplication@1@AEAVMessageStoreFactory@1@AEBVSessionSettings@1@AEAVLogFactory@1@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl StartExecutor(void *)" (?StartExecutor@@$$FYAHPEAX@Z)   OFI_FIX_Executor    D:\FIX\RRM_FIX\FIX_RRM(final)\FIXServer\OFI_FIX_Executor\OFI_FIX_Executor\OFI_FIX_ExecutorDlg.obj   1   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2028 unresolved token (0A0026C0) "public: __cdecl FIX::ThreadedSSLSocketAcceptor::ThreadedSSLSocketAcceptor(class FIX::Application &,class FIX::MessageStoreFactory &,class FIX::SessionSettings const &,class FIX::LogFactory &)" (??0ThreadedSSLSocketAcceptor@FIX@@$$FQEAA@AEAVApplication@1@AEAVMessageStoreFactory@1@AEBVSessionSettings@1@AEAVLogFactory@1@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl StartExecutor(void *)" (?StartExecutor@@$$FYAHPEAX@Z)   OFI_FIX_Executor    D:\FIX\RRM_FIX\FIX_RRM(final)\FIXServer\OFI_FIX_Executor\OFI_FIX_Executor\OFI_FIX_ExecutorDlg.obj   1   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl FIX::ThreadedSSLSocketAcceptor::ThreadedSSLSocketAcceptor(class FIX::Application &,class FIX::MessageStoreFactory &,class FIX::SessionSettings const &,class FIX::LogFactory &)" (??0ThreadedSSLSocketAcceptor@FIX@@$$FQEAA@AEAVApplication@1@AEAVMessageStoreFactory@1@AEBVSessionSettings@1@AEAVLogFactory@1@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl StartExecutor(void *)" (?StartExecutor@@$$FYAHPEAX@Z)    OFI_FIX_Executor    D:\FIX\RRM_FIX\FIX_RRM(final)\FIXServer\OFI_FIX_Executor\OFI_FIX_Executor\OFI_FIX_ExecutorDlg.obj   1   


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl FIX::SSLSocketAcceptor::SSLSocketAcceptor(class FIX::Application &,class FIX::MessageStoreFactory &,class FIX::SessionSettings const &,class FIX::LogFactory &)" (??0SSLSocketAcceptor@FIX@@$$FQEAA@AEAVApplication@1@AEAVMessageStoreFactory@1@AEBVSessionSettings@1@AEAVLogFactory@1@@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl StartExecutor(void *)" (?StartExecutor@@$$FYAHPEAX@Z)    OFI_FIX_Executor    D:\FIX\RRM_FIX\FIX_RRM(final)\FIXServer\OFI_FIX_Executor\OFI_FIX_Executor\OFI_FIX_ExecutorDlg.obj   1
```

Does this required any additional lib or dll ?

Comment: You say you "define HAVE_SSL 1" but did you defined that when building quickfix?

Comment: I put # define HAVE_SSL 1 in config_windows.h file of quickfix

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild quickfix with SSL:

1. Uncomment `#define HAVE_SSL 1` in `src/config_windows.h`
2. Call `cmake -S . -DHAVE_SSL=1` (you may need to set `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` env var to the OpenSSL path first, e.g. `set OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=C:\openssl-1.1.0f-vs2015\`) from the quickfix directory
3. Call `msbuild quickfix.sln`

Then you should be able to build a sample app (just make sure to add `src\C++\release\quickfix.lib` to your linker settings):

```
#define HAVE_SSL 1
#include <quickfix/SSLSocketAcceptor.h>

int main()
{
    FIX::NullApplication app{};
    FIX::MemoryStoreFactory factory{};
    FIX::SessionSettings settings{};
    FIX::SSLSocketAcceptor acceptor{ app, factory, settings };
}
```